# Find a divisor k of 120 such that $<a^{92}> = <a^k>$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given that $|a| = 120$. I am asked to find $|a^{92}|$ which I have found to be 30. I am then asked to find the divisor $k$ of 120 such that $<a^{92}> = <a^k>$. I know from a theorem that $<a^k> = <a^{gcd(n,k)}>$.

I am unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: What does mean $<a^k>$,  please?

Comment: well, $<a>$ denotes the cyclic subgroup of a group $G$ generated by $a$

Comment: You're using $k$ for two different things, and I think it confuses you. The first time you're using it as the "associate" of $92$, the second time as a free variable in a formula.

Comment: Have you tried just applying the formula you were given?  If $n=120$ and $k=92$, what is $\gcd(n,k)$?

Comment: (Note that you can get the same result by noticing that $|a^{92}|=30$, and finding another $k$ such that  $a^k$ that has order 30; since $a$ has order $120$, can you see why choosing $k=120/30$ works?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula $\langle a^k\rangle = \langle a^{\gcd(n,k)}\rangle$, with $k=92$, and you're done.

Comment: what is n? is it 120 since $|a| =120$?

Comment: which would be $<a^4>$?

Comment: @rover2 Yes, $n$ is the order of $a$.

Comment: @rover2 Wherever that formula is written down in your book, they should've said what $n$ is.